# How to deploy all modern tool (Ruby, Node.js, Bower, Grunt, Jekyll) in GitLab CI in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gruntjs, bower, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using `image: ruby:2.3.1` from gitlab CI. Need to deploy following packages.

1. NPM v3.10.3
2. Bower v1.7.9
3. Grunt
4. Bundle v1.13.2
5. Jekyll v3.3.0

Moreover how to ensure that each build gitlab should not re-download these packages (i mean re-usability of same)

Comment: After lot of effort I found this code works :). Sharing will good people out there. This script will install most of the tools for hassle free development on gitlab-ci. Gitlab rocks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After lot of effort, I found this code works :). Sharing with the good people out there. This script will install most of the tools for hassle free development on gitlab-ci. Gitlab rocks

```
image: ruby:2.3.1

cache:
    paths:
    - bower_components/
    - node_modules/

before_script:
    - ruby -v
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get install -y libssl-dev build-essential wget
    - wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.29.0/install.sh | bash
    - source /root/.bashrc
    - nvm install 6.6.0
    - nvm use 6.6.0
    - node -v
    - npm -v
    - npm install    
    - npm install -g bower@1.7.9
    - bower -v
    - bower install --allow-root 
    - npm install -g grunt-cli@1.2.0
    - npm install -g grunt@1.0.1
    - grunt --version
    - gem install bundler -v '1.13.2'
    - bundle --version
    - bundle install
    - gem install jekyll -v '3.3.0'
    - jekyll --version

pages:
    stage: deploy
    script:
    - grunt fullbuild
    artifacts:
        paths:
        - _site

only:
    - master
```

Comment: installing node this was the only way I got npm commands to work on GitLab CI/CD, thanks!